# Cookies add to CookiesConrainer not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

Hello i need to create  cookies and add them to CookiesConrainer but after first loop i am  getting error

```
System.Net.CookieException: The 'Name'=' PAIS' part of the cookie is invalid.
at System.Net.Cookie.set_Name(String value)
```

You can see that this is the second value in the var cookie(i inserted the string)
 this what i have inside  var cookie

> "INICIO=CU; PAIS=EN; CODIGO_PRODUCTO=413; COD_IDIOMISO=en;
>   PD_STATEFUL_e1ffdfe8-6551-11e3-99b3-005056b60460=%2FSGLKYHP;
>   PD-S-SESSION-ID=2_r"

```
var cookie = browser.Eval("document.cookie");

                    string[] arrCookie;
                    string[] allcookies = cookie.Split(';');
                    CookieContainer Cc = new CookieContainer();

   for (int i = 0; i < allcookies.Length; i++)
       {
           arrCookie = allcookies[i].Split('=');
           Cookie TCookie = new Cookie();    
           TCookie.Name = arrCookie[0].ToString();//on second loop it getting error
           TCookie.Value = arrCookie[1].ToString();
           TCookie.Domain = "www.cash.com";
           Cc.Add(TCookie);
        }
```

Comment: arrCookie[0] have the name and arrCookie[1] have the value in first loop all work,but  when i trying to build the second cookie uit fails,sow i don't think i need trim them ,otherwise it would fail in first loop too.

Comment: From your sample input, the first name doesn't need to be trimmed as it doesn't have a leading space.  Also, have you tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `Name` must be trimmed.  `" PAIS"` is invalid, while `"PAIS"` is perfectly fine.